# call trait method when struct method has same name

Tags: rust, overriding, traits

In the following code:

```
pub trait Thinger {
    fn print_thing(&self) where Self: core::fmt::Debug {
        println!("trait method: {:?}", self);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Thing(f64);

impl Thing {
    fn print_thing(&self) where Self: core::fmt::Debug {
        println!("method: {:?}", self);
    }
}

impl Thinger for Thing {}

fn main() {
    let thing = Thing(3.14);
    thing.print_thing();
}
```

how do I call `Thinger`'s `print_thing` method?
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0717f5615e10e3a1349f6db9cb9c3306

I've seen this in The Book, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

```rust
Thinger::print_thing(&thing)

<Thing as Thinger>::print_thing(&thing)
```

Here is the fragment of [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) you have been referring to.

Comment: I would add that this is called Universal Function Call Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Aleksander Krauze nailed it, but there is another way to do it for completeness:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4450b905f10198967090c8f56e3acfeb

`Thinger::print_thing(&thing);`